# how to save dynamic form data from javascript to database with a query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

So I have a script that makes dynamic form content and each input has a name of "field-1", "field-2", etc. up until the last input is created by the script.

How can I save the form made to the database?

I only know how to do this in a traditional way where you make like 5 static inputs and give them static names and ids then use the either post or get go formulate the mysql_query.

But in my case, the inputs can range from 3 - 200 inputs. and each have a similar name/id of "field+num++"

My html code:

```
<form id="myForm">
```

My JS code that will append to my HTML form:

```
    var $int = $('div.int');
    $int.html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace(/(\d+)(.+)/,function(str,s1,s2){
            var text = s2.split('.');
            var text2 = text[1].split('-');
            var text3 = text2[1].split(' ');
            return '<input class="r" name="scene-"' + s1 + ' value="'+ s1.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '') +'" />' +
            '<input class="r" name="int_ext-"' + s1 + ' value="'+ text[0].replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '') +'" />' +
            '<input class="r" name="scene_desct-"' + s1 + ' value="'+ text2[0].replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '') +'" />' +
            '<input class="r" name="day_night-"' + s1 + ' value="'+ text3[1].replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '') +'" />';
        });
   });
```

My HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your field e.g. `foo[]` you will get an array `$_POST['foo']` containing all values. You can also iterate over the elements in `$_POST` - whatever you prefer. But iterating over all POST data probably not the best idea..

Answer (score 0):

When you send the data to the backend server your script will need to add the data to the database in a free form way

Create a table in your database that can accept the name of the field as well as the value in the field

e.g. the table may contain the following fields

```
id (primary key)
field_name char(20) 
value char(255)
form_name char(20)
form_id char(40)
```

This way you can store the information in a free form way. you are not tied to specific field names, you need to be able to determine which fields belong in which form so thats why the two fields form_name and form_id
the form_name is the generated form name
the form_id is the unique submitted form identifier.

The field types are arbitrary you may want to make them different lengths or even types

does that make sense?

DC

P.S. don't forget all normal security issues when entering into the database.

Comment: It doesn't matter so much about your javascript. javascript runs inside the users browser, it cannot directly add information to a database. When the user clicks the submit button the form data is sent back to the webserver, in the example you gave it goes back to the same page that has the javascript on it. Its that page whether it be php, or asp or some other scripting language needs to create a connection to the database and store the information in a way similar to what i described.